# REST - saving related entities

Tags: rest

I'm developing an application in which user during the registration adds locals which owns. After user finishes register process I want to create new User in database with related Locals.

What is best practice of designing API for that. What should be naming strategy for that problem?

What I'm doing right now is:

@PostMapping("/owner-registration/users)

I'm taking whole data : user, realted locals. I'm creating User by UserFacade in module user, and then creating related locals with LocalFacade in module locals

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding I would design

```
@PostMapping("/users")
```

and

```
@PostMapping("/locals")
```

where the entities get created.

If both creations succeed, you could update the `user` like

```
@PutMapping("/users/related-locals")
```

Surely you also could do

```
@PutMapping("/locals/related-users")
```

If you need to create an `user` in a single operation (attaching `related-locals` directly) you would need to

- create `local` first,
- get the `id` or `link` of the newly created `local`
- create the `user` and add the `id` or `link` under `related-locals` to it in the client and `POST` it.

This means, that if the creation of the `user` fails for some reason, you end up with dangling `locals` in your database.

Another possibility is using *Multipart*. With Multipart you can have two different objects in the same RequestBody.

```
@PostMapping("/users")
```

then could accept such multipart request, where the `user` and `locals` are included. Your server-side implementation would then have to assume, that those `locals` map to `related-locals` in `user` and create them server-side and add them to the `user` (by `id` or `link` like before). If any of the operations would fail, you could roll-back the entire request and keep your database clean.

Comment: What if I want to remove one related-user? Should I use something like @DeleteMapping("/locals/related-users/userId") ?

Comment: If you do not delete the referenced user, I would update the user with the reference removed.
If you delete the referenced user, the delete mapping to the referenced user itself would be the way to go. References should be updated by the service behind the scenes.